# Do we solve the recurrence relations by expanding the terms?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrence relation:

$a_k=2 a_{k-1}+3a_{k-2}$ with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$.

I have expanded the recurrence relation:

$$a_k=2 (2 a_{k-2}+3 a_{k-3})+ 3(2 a_{k-3}+3 a_{k-4})= 2^2 a_{k-2}+ 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot a_{k-3}+ 3^2 a_{k-4}= 2^3 a_{k-3}+ 3 \cdot 2^2 \cdot a_{k-4}+3 \cdot 2^3 a_{k-4}+ 3^2 \cdot 2^2 \cdot a_{k-5}+ 3^2 \cdot 2 a_{k-5}+3^3 a_{k-6}$$

Do we continue with the same way? Or is there an other way to solve the recurrence relation?

Also, is there an other way rather than the expansion of the terms and the use of the characteristic equation?

**EDIT**: Also suppose that we have to solve the recurrence relation

$$d_k=4 d_{k-2}, \text{ where } d_0=1 \text{ and } d_1=-1.$$

I have done the following:

\begin{align*}d_k=4d_{k-2}&=2^2d_{k-2} \\ &=2^2\left (2^2d_{(k-2)-2}\right )=2^4d_{k-4} \\ &  =2^4\left (2^2d_{(k-4)-2}\right )=2^6d_{k-6} \\ & = 2^6\left (2^2d_{(k-6)-2}\right )=2^8d_{k-8} \\ & = \ldots \\ & = 2^id_{k-i}\ , \ \ i \text{ even}\end{align*}

If $k$ even, then at the last step we have for $i=k$ (since $k$ is the maximum even number  $\leq k$) : $d_k=2^kd_{k-k}=2^kd_0=2^k$.

If $k$ odd, then at the last step we have for $i=k-1$ (since $k-1$ is the maximum even number $\leq k$) : $d_k=2^{k-1}d_{k-(k-1)}=2^{k-1}d_1=-2^{k-1}$.

How can we find the general form for the terms of the recurrence relation? Or do we distinguish cases when $k$ is even and odd?

Comment: Finding a closed form? Typically I'd expand a few terms and get a feeling for what the closed form should look like, then prove it with induction.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Binet formula for Fibonacci numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the characteristic equation method, it's quick and straightforward. The following is an ad hoc solution for this particular recurrence relation, just for fun. We have
$$a_k=2a_{k-1}+3a_{k-2}$$
$$a_k+a_{k-1}=3a_{k-1}+3a_{k-2}$$
Now we can set $b_k=a_k+a_{k-1}$ and get
$$b_k=3b_{k-1}\qquad b_1=a_1+a_0=3$$
Which implies $b_k=3^k$. Finally
$$a_k=b_k-a_{k-1}\implies a_k=3^k-a_{k-1}\qquad a_0=1$$
$$a_k=3^k-3^{k-1}+3^{k-2}-\cdots+(-1)^k=(-1)^k\cdot\frac{(-3)^{k+1}-1}{(-3)-1}$$
$$a_k=\frac{3^{k+1}+(-1)^k}{4}$$

Comment: We get that $a_k=3^k-3^{k+1}+3^{k-2}-a_{k-3}$. $$$$

How do we get the relation $a_k=3^{k}-3^{k-1}+3^{k-2}- \dots+ (-1)^k$ ? $$$$

And why is the latter equal to $(-1)^k (3^k+3^{k-1}+\dots+1)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

For 1., the roots of the characteristic equation $x^2=2x+3$ are $x=3$ and $x=-1$,

so the solution is $a_k=A3^n+B(-1)^n$.

Can you solve for $A$ and $B$ using the initial conditions $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$?

This method is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

Comment: Thanks! Could you also check my question at the edited part of my main question?

Comment: You probably should post a separate question for more details, but you could solve it the way I solved your original question to get $d_k=C2^n+D(-2)^n$